# PHP imap_open Couldn't open stream (1 out of 5 times) and too slow

Tags: php, imap

So, I am trying work on PHP Imap functionality for building a small mail client. I have currently worked on this endless scrolling functionality using jQuery to retrieve mails .

For every scroll down event selected numbers of mails(using `imap_overview`) are retrieved. However, I get this error: `imap_open` Couldn't open stream every 1 out of 5 times. What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone please throw some light.

Also,  `imap_overview` takes it own sweet time to retrieve mails depending on the size. For example I tried to retrieve mails from my gmail account with overview parameter set to "1:25", "1:50" and so on. For every such run the time used to get multiplied. Is there are a way around to this issue? Or basically we just retrieve the number of mails you need?

Comment: have you managed to solve this problem? i am facing it too now, imap_open is too slow...

Comment: Well, I ended up downloading mails and storing it in my database at regular intervals. .This gives a much better performance and flexibility (for searching and many more things)..